# Eclipse Editor Plugin: Textmarker overwrites style information in the editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Im trying to create a lightweight C++ Editor with the help of libclang.

I use a new problemmarker type to mark the compiler warnings and errors given by clang and the token ranges to do syntax coloring.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, the squiggly lines of the error markers overwrite the syntax coloring. Is there a PresentationReconciler that takes into account that some marked lines could still have other style information?

I added some code snippets that might be relevant to solve the problem:
my plugin.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            name="CXX Editor"
            extensions="cpp"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            contributorClass="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicTextEditorActionContributor"
            class="cppeditor.editors.CppEditor"
            id="cppeditor.editors.CppEditor">
      </editor>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="cppeditor.problemmarker"
         name="clang Error"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
      <super
            type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker">
      </super>
      <super
            type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker">
      </super>
      <persistent
            value="true">
      </persistent>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

The method to add markers to the IFile resource:

```
public void addMarkerToFile(IFile file, IDocument fileDocument) throws CoreException, BadLocationException{
    IMarker marker = file.createMarker("cppeditor.problemmarker");
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, this.severity);
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, this.message);
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, this.line);
    int startOffset = fileDocument.getLineOffset(this.line-1);
    int endOffset = fileDocument.getNumberOfLines() > this.line ? 
             fileDocument.getLineOffset(this.line) : fileDocument.getLength()-1;
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, startOffset);
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, endOffset);
}
```

The "createPresentation" method of the PresentationRepairer

```
@Override
public void createPresentation(TextPresentation presentation, ITypedRegion region) {
    CppDocument doc = (CppDocument) this.fDocument;
    Token[] newTokens = doc.getTokens();
    if(newTokens != oldTokens){
        for(Token t : newTokens){
            addRange(
                presentation,
                t.getStart(),
                t.getEnd() - t.getStart(),
                attributeMap.get(t.getKind()));     
        }
        oldTokens = newTokens;
    }
}
```

note: I already asked this question in the eclipse forums but nobody answered it... (see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1086329/))

Comment: You could try looking at the Java editor source since it seems to be able to do this. It just seems to use `DefaultDamagerRepairer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. After adding markers to the file, the "createPresentation" method is called again, this time because the marker region was invalidated.

This is why the `if(newTokens != oldTokens)` broke the syntax highlighting at the invalidated areas. I removed the `if` to fix the problem.